# Refer Object's Property by string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to call object's property by its key name?

I want to update user's profile from the data in the cookie. So I have the following code

```
bool PropertyChanged = false;
UserProfile ThisUserProfile = context.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.Id == int.Parse(GetCookieValue(UserIdString)));
if(ThisUserProfile.Property1 != GetCookieValue("Property1")){
    ThisUserProfile.Property1 = GetCookieValue("Property1")
    PropertyChanged = true
}
if(ThisUserProfile.Property2 != GetCookieValue("Property2")){
    ThisUserProfile.Property2 = GetCookieValue("Property2")
    PropertyChanged = true
}
if(ThisUserProfile.Property3 != GetCookieValue("Property3")){
    ThisUserProfile.Property3 = GetCookieValue("Property3")
    PropertyChanged = true
}

// and many more properties.....

if(PropertyChanged)
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Is it possible to write a method to update a property object as following?

```
void UpdateIfChanged(string Key){
    ThisUserProfile[key] = GetCookieValue("key")
    PropertyChanged = true
}
```

So I can create a string array and use a foreach loop to do everything in one go?

Comment: You can use PropertyReflector class: https://github.com/ccollie/Guanima.Redis/blob/master/Guanima.Redis/Utils/PropertyReflector.cs `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some reflection.

```
public static void SetValue(object entity, string propertyName, object value)
{
            try
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
                object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
                pi.SetValue(entity, safeValue, null);
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
            {
                //Handle casting between different assemblies...
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                    Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
                    object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(t, value);
                    pi.SetValue(entity, safeValue, null);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return;
}
```

Then use this method like this:

```
string[] userProperties = {"Username", "Email", "Address"};

foreach (string s in userProperties)
{
    //You could set up your application so cookie property names are the same as your entity's...
    SetValue(ThisUserProfile, s, value);
}
```

Also adapt the `try/catch` blocks of `SetValue` to your needs. You have not specified the type of `ThisUserProfile` so I couldn't fully test if this is functional in your specific case.

You should know that reflection is known to be slow, so use it only if you really need it.

Since you are using Entity Framework and you are not using the entity's usual `set` accessor (which notify the change tracker of ongoing changes) you may have to set the entity's `State` property to `EntityState.Modified` yourself before committing changes (`SaveChanges`).

`GetValue` might also be useful, if you plan on using reflection to retrieve values from another object

```
public static object GetValue(object entity, string propertyName)
{
    try
    {
       return entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(entity, null);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with Northwind. The database doesn't budge. using (NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                Order o = context.Orders.Single(ord => ord.OrderID == 10248);
                SetValue(o, "CustomerID", "Hellworld");
            }

Comment: @HoyCheung Can you debug and see if `SetValue` does indeed change the property's value ?

Comment: I have changed a different database. still can't update the database. What am I suppose to put in the third parameter, object value?

Comment: @HoyCheung You have not answered my previous question. Are you even debugging ? The first parameter is the entity, the second is the name of the property you want to set the value, and the third is the actual value.

Comment: Yes I have. I can see all properties in entity. Only nothing changed in the database after the execution of the method.

Comment: @HoyCheung Try explicitly setting the entity's `State` to `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: At where do I insert this line? Do I have to SaveChanges()?

Comment: @HoyCheung Yes, before SaveChanges()

Comment: Thank you. The code is a bit daunting. I spent quite a lot of time in looking into each line. It's a shame that Entity Framework doesn't provide native method to achieve that.